# ManyToMany through Queryset Django 2.2

Tags: python, django, orm

I have 3 models and their relation:

```
class Itinerary(models.Model):
    origin_dest = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default="")
    travelers = models.ManyToManyField('Traveler')
    flights = models.ManyToManyField('Flight')

class Traveler(models.Model):
    pass

class Flight(models.Model):
    pass
```

An Itinerary has one or many flights (stop vs nonstop) and a flight can belong to more than one itinerary. Also, a traveler can have many itineraries and an itinerary can have many travelers. Here is why:

Let's say `traveler 1` has a flight from JFK-LAX which has 1 stop in MIA. Then the Itinerary will have 2 flights (JFK-MIA, MIA-LAX). Now let's say we have another person, `traveler 2` who has an itinerary from MIA-LAX which is the same flight as `traveler 1` going from MIA-JFK (different itinerary instance but same flight shared). Therefore in this case, there are 2 itinerary where a single flight (MIA-LAX) belongs to those two itineraries, hence the ManyToMany relationship.

Now what I'd like to do ideally is query all travelers that are on a particular flight through the itinerary model. Somethind like this:

```
flight.itinerary_set.travelers #=> return the number of travelers that are on that specific flight.
```

Comment: I think it has to be done in 2 stages, the first for the itineraries and the second for the travelers

Comment: Sure. I could query the itinerary then for each of them grab the traveler but I wonder if there is a nice way to do that through Django’s ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have an intermediate object, e.g. `Booking`, that's always a single flight and a single traveler. That way there's no potential for confusion regarding which traveler is on which flight, which seems like a pretty important distinction, unless for some reason that's not relevant in your use case.

Example models for that case:

```
from django.db import models


class Traveler(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Flight(models.Model):
    number = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number


class Itinerary(models.Model):
    pass


class Booking(models.Model):
    itinerary = models.ForeignKey(
        Itinerary,
        related_name='bookings',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    traveler = models.ForeignKey(
        Traveler,
        related_name='bookings',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    flight = models.ForeignKey(
        Flight,
        related_name='bookings',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Partial output from test case is below. Note that this creates two separate itineraries with independent bookings on the same flight.

```
>>> from itineraries.models import Traveler, Flight, Itinerary, Booking
>>> 
>>> f = Flight.objects.create(number='JAL1')
>>> 
>>> Booking.objects.create(
...     itinerary=Itinerary.objects.create(),
...     traveler=Traveler.objects.create(name='kungphu'),
...     flight=f,
... )
<Booking: Booking object (5)>
>>> 
>>> Booking.objects.create(
...     itinerary=Itinerary.objects.create(),
...     traveler=Traveler.objects.create(name='Cyzanfar'),
...     flight=f,
... )
<Booking: Booking object (6)>
>>> 
>>> # Travelers on flight f:
>>> for t in Traveler.objects.filter(bookings__flight=f):
...     print(t)
... 
kungphu
Cyzanfar
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you found this useful, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: quick follow up. Would it make more sense to use django aggregation instead of creating another table?

Comment: I don't think aggregation could really serve the same purpose. The models you originally had don't provide for definitely knowing which traveler was on which flight, so if that's the information you need, there'd have to be at least some relational tweaks to actually save that information.